# Create a per row Lookup and Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, lookup

I am using the following code to dynamically lookup a table name from another table.

The trouble is that the @tablevalue value that is being returned is static. Whereas what I need to do is to bring back the [Tariff Lookup] value that is related to that customer. (so per row)

Here is my code so far:

```
DECLARE @tablevalue nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @tablevalue  = [Tariff Lookup]
FROM [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls];

SELECT @sql = N'UPDATE [APRW14_FFA68878_Calls] 
SET    [APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Sell Price] = [test].[dbo].' + @tablevalue +'.[Peak]/60*[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Duration (secs)]
FROM   [Test].[dbo].[DaisyRates_May2014]
INNER JOIN [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls] on [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[ChargeCode] = [Test].[dbo].[DaisyRates_May2014].[Chargecode]';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
PRINT @tablevalue;
```

Can anyone help with the correct syntax?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you know the customer?  What field identifies them?

Comment: I have a customer table, that holds the Customer to Tariff mapping. I have already performed a UPDATE to pull the Tariff information from the Customers table into the [Tariff Lookup] field. I now need o perform an additional lookup/calculation based in that value.

Comment: Shouldn't you just be able to add the customer to the fields you are joining on?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Even if a cursor is used (which is inefficient - sql is set based), wouldn't he still need to identify which record goes with that specific customer he is trying to update???

Comment: Thanks @t-clausen.dk - Can you help me out with the correct syntax for an SQL cursor please? Based on my requirement to perform an update statement for each row in my table, using the [Tariff Lookup] as a variable